# I'm using raty.js star rating system, how do I show the equivalent integer value of star for my avg. rating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, raty

The code below will show for example:

Average Rating

**

Based on 2 reviews

---

So since it's average rating is 2 stars, how do I show the integer value "2"? So it will be like:

** 2

```
<h2 class="avg-rating">Average Rating</h2>
<div class="average-review-rating" data-score=<%= @average_review %>></div>
<span class="number-of-reviews">Based on <%= @book.reviews.count %> reviews</span>




<script>
    $('.average-review-rating').raty({
        readOnly: true,
        path: '/assets/',
        score: function() {
            return $(this).attr('data-score')
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just:

```
<div class="average-review-rating" data-score=<%= @average_review %>> <%= @average_review %></div>
```

This will output the average score as a literal value.

Comment: When I push to Heroku, the star images are broken, do you have any idea?